# sql stores text string as "Array"

Tags: php, sql, forms

I've found a weird bug that only occurs in 1 of my many forms, every form is used in the same way , but `$codering = ['RF-013.12'];` stores "Array" in my table? and the field next to it is supposed to be 18 but stores a value of 0. 
 I think i'm missing something here. Can someone review my code? Thanks!
[image]

```
<

?php
         if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'heijsdb_user';
            $dbpass = 'maus';

            $conn = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($dbhost,  $dbuser,  $dbpass));

            if(! $conn ) {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]));
            }
//variable aanmaken van formulier
                $controleur = $_SESSION["username"];
                $codering = ['RF-013.12'];
                $revisie = ['18'];
                $g11 = $_POST['11000'];
                $g15 = $_POST['15000'];
                $g110 = $_POST['110000'];
                $g15c = $_POST['15000c'];
                $g21 = $_POST['21000'];
                $g25 = $_POST['25000'];
                $g210 = $_POST['210000'];
                $g25c = $_POST['25000c'];
                $g31 = $_POST['31000'];
                $g35 = $_POST['35000'];
                $g310 = $_POST['310000'];
                $g35c = $_POST['35000c'];
                $g41 = $_POST['41000'];
                $g45 = $_POST['45000'];
                $g410 = $_POST['410000'];
                $g45c = $_POST['45000c'];
                $g61 = $_POST['61000'];
                $g65 = $_POST['65000'];
                $g610 = $_POST['610000'];
                $g65c = $_POST['65000c'];
                $g71 = $_POST['71000'];
                $g75 = $_POST['75000'];
                $g710 = $_POST['710000'];
                $g75c = $_POST['75000c'];
                $g81 = $_POST['81000'];
                $g85 = $_POST['85000'];
                 $g810 = $_POST['810000'];
                 $g85c = $_POST['85000c'];
                 $g91 = $_POST['91000'];
                 $g95 = $_POST['95000'];
                 $g910 = $_POST['910000'];
                 $g95c = $_POST['95000c'];
                 $g9a1 = $_POST['9a1000'];
                 $g9a5 = $_POST['9a5000'];
                 $g9a10 = $_POST['9a10000'];
                 $g9a5c = $_POST['9a5000c'];
                 $g101 = $_POST['101000'];
                 $g105 = $_POST['105000'];
                 $g1010 = $_POST['1010000'];
                 $g105c = $_POST['105000c'];
                 $g111 = $_POST['111000'];
                 $g115 = $_POST['115000'];
                 $g1110 = $_POST['1110000'];
                 $g115c = $_POST['115000c'];
                 $g121 = $_POST['121000'];
                 $g125 = $_POST['125000'];
                 $g1210 = $_POST['1210000'];
                 $g125c = $_POST['125000c'];
                 $g131 = $_POST['131000'];
                 $g135 = $_POST['135000'];
                 $g1310 = $_POST['1310000'];
                 $g135c = $_POST['135000c'];
                 $g141 = $_POST['141000'];
                 $g145 = $_POST['145000'];
                 $g1410 = $_POST['1410000'];
                 $g145c = $_POST['145000c'];
                 $g151 = $_POST['151000'];
                 $g155 = $_POST['155000'];
                 $g1510 = $_POST['1510000'];
                 $g155c = $_POST['155000c'];
                 $g181 = $_POST['181000'];
                 $g185 = $_POST['185000'];
                 $g1810 = $_POST['1810000'];
                 $g185c = $_POST['185000c'];
                 $g191 = $_POST['191000'];
                 $g195 = $_POST['195000'];
                 $g1910 = $_POST['1910000'];
                 $g195c = $_POST['195000c'];
                 $g201 = $_POST['201000'];
                 $g205 = $_POST['205000'];
                 $g2010 = $_POST['2010000'];
                 $g205c = $_POST['205000c'];


            $sql = "INSERT INTO weegschaal(controleur, codering, revisie, inpak1000, inpak5000, inpak10000, inpak5000c, kruiden1000, kruiden5000, kruiden10000, kruiden5000c, linco601000, linco605000, linco6010000, linco605000c, linco301000, linco305000, linco3010000, linco305000c, vleugel1000, vleugel5000, vleugel10000, vleugel5000c, meijnborst1000, meijnborst5000, meijnborst10000, meijnborst5000c, meijnpoot1000, meijnpoot5000, meijnpoot10000, meijnpoot5000c, divers1000, divers5000, divers10000, divers5000c, td1000, td5000, td10000, td5000c, batchborst1000, batchborst5000, batchborst10000, batchborst5000c, organen1000, organen5000, organen10000, organen5000c, dienst1000, dienst5000, dienst10000, dienst5000c, inpakreserve1000, inpakreserve5000, inpakreserve10000, inpakreserve5000c, foodpoten1000, foodpoten5000, foodpoten10000, foodpoten5000c, foodborst1000, foodborst5000, foodborst10000, foodborst5000c, reservedini1000, reservedini5000, reservedini10000, reservedini5000c, reserve1dini1000, reserve1dini5000, reserve1dini10000, reserve1dini5000c, inpaktafel1000, inpaktafel5000, inpaktafel10000, inpaktafel5000c) VALUES 
            ('$controleur','$codering','$revisie','$g11', '$g15', '$g110', '$g15c', '$g21','$g25','$g210','$g25c','$g31','$g35','$g310','$g35c','$g41','$g45','$g410','$g45c','$g61','$g65','$g610','$g65c','$g71','$g75','$g710','$g75c','$g81','$g85','$g810','$g85c','$g91','$g95','$g910','$g95c','$g9a1','$g9a5','$g9a10','$g9a5c','$g101','$g105','$g1010','$g105c','$g111','$g115','$g1110','$g115c','$g121','$g125','$g1210','$g125c','$g131','$g135','$g1310','$g135c','$g141','$g145','$g1410','$g145c','$g151','$g155','$g1510','$g155c','$g181','$g185','$g1810','$g185c','$g191','$g195','$g1910','$g195c','$g201','$g205','$g2010','$g205c') ";
            mysqli_select_db($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], 'heijsdb');
            $retval = mysqli_query( $conn ,  $sql);

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]));
            }
            echo "Formulier verstuurd.";
```

Comment: codering field is  text latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: If you enable error-reporting and check your logs, I can nearly *guarantee* that you have "*Array to string conversion*" errors.

Comment: String representation of array is word __Array__

Comment: Your error is this: `$codering = ['RF-013.12'];` - that is an array with 1 element, you would want `$codering = 'RF-013.12';` instead. Note the brackets are gone.

Comment: *"but `$codering = ['RF-013.12'];` stores "Array" in my table"* - That is correct and that is what that syntax does. `[]` is the syntax for "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal. When you do :

```
$codering = ['RF-013.12'];
```

Is same as :

```
$codering = array('RF-013.12');
```

So if you try to use your array like string, php write *array* instead.

If you wanna store [something] (a string with [] character) you need :

```
$codering = "[something]";
```

If you realy need to store an array, ou can serialize him.

Example :

[serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

```
string serialize ( mixed $value )
```

or

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth = 512 ]] )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change this:

```
$codering = ['RF-013.12'];
$revisie = ['18'];
```

to this:

```
$codering = 'RF-013.12';
$revisie = '18';
```

I think that you don't need array into your database in this case so change the array variables into simple string to solve you problem

If you want to insert an array into a database I advise you to use 
[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Example:

```
json_encode($yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your creating array .  `[]` is array syntax

```
$codering = ['RF-013.12'];
$revisie = ['18'];
```

You need to pass as string like this

```
$codering = 'RF-013.12';
$revisie = '18';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, because you pass an array containing one element to your database.
What does the structure of your table says?
If you try to store an array, try using a foreign table with a reference on your existing table.

If you want to save RF-013.12 as a string, just use `$codering = "RF-013.12";`.
If you have an array with RF-013.12 as a key, try to reference that value.

Greetz.